# Reference for surface area (volume) formula

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

I am having a hard time finding a reference book for the following theorem.  It seems to be always presented in special cases in elementary books, and then the advanced (graduate) books skip it get bogged down in complicated technology.

> Theorem: Suppose $S$ is a smooth surface in $\mathbb R^n$.  In other words, there is a function $f : V \to \mathbb R^n$, where $U \subseteq V$ are bounded open subsets of $\mathbb R^m$ ($m \leq n$) such that the closure $\bar U \subseteq V$, $f$ is injective and continuously differentiable on $V$, and $S = f[U]$.  Then the volume of $S$ is: $\operatorname{vol}_f(S)=$ [insert formula involving Jacobian of $f$].  And if $g : U’ \to \mathbb R^n$ is any other smooth parameterization of $S$, then $\operatorname{vol}_g(S) = \operatorname{vol}_f(S)$.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Mathematical Analysis II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3662489910) by Vladimir Zorich.